Why aren't my Python packages installing?
(sorry if my formatting is off)
So I was trying to make a Stock Predictor using a tutorial Stock Predictor and when I do the command to import everything it gives me an error for fbprophet. Could anybody help
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [2 lines of output]
      <string>:61: DeprecationWarning: Attribute s is deprecated and will be removed in Python 3.14; use value instead
      Cython>=0.22 and NumPy are required.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Thanks for any help
I tried different options of fixing it like
python3 -m pip install fbprophet

and also uninstalling Cython and Numpy but they didn't work.
Thank you. Help would be appreciated.

@esqew I have all of the requirements for fbprophet and everything is installed. And by the way I am using a virtual environment. I don't know where it went wrong.

I have fixed it. Instead of putting "fbprophet" you put "prophet" as fbprophet has been outdated.

I have fixed it. Instead of putting "fbprophet" you put "prophet" as fbprophet has been outdated.
